# Replace Broken URL Link using iText7 or PDFsharp in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, url, itext7, pdfsharp

I'm trying to replace broken urls for different pdfs, this is what I have currently:

```
if (replacementURL != "") {

    PdfDictionary dictJS = new PdfDictionary();
    dictJS.Elements["/A"] = new PdfName("/c#");
    dictJS.Elements["/c#"] = new PdfStringObject(document, (replacementURL + "\", true"));
                                                       
    document.Internals.AddObject(dictJS);

    PdfDictionary dict = new PdfDictionary();
    PdfArray array = new PdfArray();
    dict.Elements["/Names"] = array;
    array.Elements.Add(new PdfString("EmbeddedC#"));
    array.Elements.Add(PdfInternals.GetReference(dictJS));
    document.Internals.AddObject(dictJS);

    PdfDictionary group = new PdfDictionary();
    group.Elements["/CSharp"] = PdfInternals.GetReference(dict);
                                                 
    document.Internals.Catalog.Elements["/Names"] = group;

                                                    
 }
```

I already have the code that searches and picks out the links to find the urls, but the actual replacement is what's been getting me stumped. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to replace the target of a link annotation? Or do you want to replace an URL printed in the static content of a page? Or is the URL to replace even embedded in some JavaScript?